# I have excel dates entered as 1/9/18, and I'd like to change them to 1/1/09

Tags: excel, date, time-series

In the format 1/9/18 the date is wrong. But the true date is made up of the wrong dates' month as month and day as year.

So I'd like to convert 1/9/18 to 1/1/09 meaning January 1, 2009.

Comment: What is the rule that says `1/9/18` should be converted to `1/1/09`?

Comment: How were the dates "entered"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your computer's regional system uses a DMY 'short date' then put this in an unused column to the right.

```
=date(2000+month(a1), day(a1), 1)
```

But if your computer's regional system uses a MDY 'short date' then put this in an unused column to the right.

```
=date(2000+day(a1), month(a1), 1)
```

Comment: Thanks Jeeped. This type of thinking worked. Namely, Date(year,month,day) and grabbing them in other cells.